# Summarizing max. values for each row in an excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been trying to come up with a formula to summarize and sort sales results in a large excel file.

Ideally, I would like to summarize rows with the 5 highest value (by count) for different companies in the table (H1:N7).

[image]

Could you help me with the appropriate formula to use? Any help is hugely appreciated. Thank you for your help.

ps.First time asking a question here. I do apologize if this is inappropriate. Please bear with me.

Cheers!

edit:

Apparently I only have 5 minutes to edit my comment and have 300 character limits.

Thank you for taking the time to explain the solution in detail, much appreciated.

However, this sample is already taken from a pivot table which has around 3500 rows with 20 or so "Groups".

Let me give a more detailed example (I've edited my first post to add a screenshot, please refer to it);

There are 20 groups in column L (of which we are looking only at one), and when I filter by "column P" the table does so only within "column M" for each separate firm.

Is there any way for me to extract the highest valued column M items for each group? (I've highlighted them in the second screenshot I included)

Do you think it can be done using a pivot table, or should a formula be used to extract the information I described? Thank you a lot.

[Second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAIhV.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Pivot Table for this.

Create your pivot table on the data, set up like this:

[image]

Click the filter icon on the personnel column header. Go to Value Filters> Top 10:

[image]

Configure it like this:

[image]

Repeat for Company, like this:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

You can rename the headers by typing over them.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain the solution in detail, much appreciated.